# Spring security fail login

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-security, spring-data

I can't login with my Spring Security.
Always redirects to my fail page.

LOGS (after i send login and pass):

```
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /j_spring_security_check at position 1 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - HttpSession returned null object for SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@a3a3121. A new one will be created.
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /j_spring_security_check at position 2 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /j_spring_security_check at position 3 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /j_spring_security_check at position 4 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter - Request is to process authentication
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager - Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy - Delegating to org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ChangeSessionIdAuthenticationStrategy@57e1bde8
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter - Authentication success. Updating SecurityContextHolder to contain: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@fec7843d: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@586034f: Username: admin; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 10.10.34.143; SessionId: 04D5F1E3C7B72570F1D4C2F7ADBC136C; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_USER
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler - Redirecting to DefaultSavedRequest Url: http://10.10.34.143:8080/app/j_spring_security_check
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy - Redirecting to 'http://10.10.34.143:8080/app/j_spring_security_check'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - SecurityContext stored to HttpSession: 'org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@fec7843d: Authentication: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@fec7843d: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@586034f: Username: admin; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 10.10.34.143; SessionId: 04D5F1E3C7B72570F1D4C2F7ADBC136C; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_USER'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /j_spring_security_check at position 1 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - Obtained a valid SecurityContext from SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT: 'org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@fec7843d: Authentication: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@fec7843d: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@586034f: Username: admin; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 10.10.34.143; SessionId: 04D5F1E3C7B72570F1D4C2F7ADBC136C; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_USER'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /j_spring_security_check at position 2 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /j_spring_security_check at position 3 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /j_spring_security_check at position 4 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter - Request is to process authentication
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter - Authentication request failed: org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationServiceException: Authentication method not supported: GET
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter - Updated SecurityContextHolder to contain null Authentication
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter - Delegating to authentication failure handler org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler@1405b08
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler - Redirecting to /login?error=Invalid%20user%20login%20or%20password
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy - Redirecting to '/app/login?error=Invalid%20user%20login%20or%20password'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /login?error=Invalid%20user%20login%20or%20password at position 1 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - HttpSession returned null object for SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@a3a3121. A new one will be created.
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /login?error=Invalid%20user%20login%20or%20password at position 2 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /login?error=Invalid%20user%20login%20or%20password at position 3 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /login?error=Invalid%20user%20login%20or%20password at position 4 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /login?error=Invalid%20user%20login%20or%20password at position 5 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'BasicAuthenticationFilter'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /login?error=Invalid%20user%20login%20or%20password at position 6 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.DefaultSavedRequest - pathInfo: both null (property equals)
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.DefaultSavedRequest - queryString: arg1=null; arg2=error=Invalid%20user%20login%20or%20password (property not equals)
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.HttpSessionRequestCache - saved request doesn't match
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /login?error=Invalid%20user%20login%20or%20password at position 7 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /login?error=Invalid%20user%20login%20or%20password at position 8 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter - Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@905571d8: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@0: RemoteIpAddress: 10.10.34.143; SessionId: 6C4EAB97775D858B3677DC3CD0A53666; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /login?error=Invalid%20user%20login%20or%20password at position 9 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /login?error=Invalid%20user%20login%20or%20password at position 10 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /login?error=Invalid%20user%20login%20or%20password at position 11 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/resources/**'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/login'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /login?error=Invalid%20user%20login%20or%20password; Attributes: [permitAll]
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@905571d8: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@0: RemoteIpAddress: 10.10.34.143; SessionId: 6C4EAB97775D858B3677DC3CD0A53666; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased - Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@34223c37, returned: 1
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Authorization successful
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor - RunAsManager did not change Authentication object
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /login?error=Invalid%20user%20login%20or%20password reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
```

Look, i have correct j_username add j_password, but still redirects to login fail page.

My security.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

    <http use-expressions="true">
        <http-basic />
        <form-login login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"
            default-target-url="/homepage" login-page="/login"
            authentication-failure-url="/login?error=Invalid%20user%20login%20or%20password" />

        <logout logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout"
            logout-success-url="/login" />

        <intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="permitAll" />

        <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/signup" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/homepage" access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/user" access="hasRole('User')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('Admin')" />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="user" password="user" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
                <user name="admin" password="admin" authorities="ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

EDIT: After POST request to j_spring_security_check, i have GET request to j_spring_security_check. I don't know why.

My Login page (index.jsp):

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Login</title>
<style type="text/css">
table {
    margin-top: 10%;
    padding: 40px;
    border: 3px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px;
    border-radius: 50px;
}

td {
    text-align: left
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div align="center">
        <c:url var="loginUrl" value="/j_spring_security_check" />
        <form action="${loginUrl}" method="post">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="login">Login:</label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="j_username" id="login"
                        style="width: 100%" required></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="password">Password:</label></td>
                    <td><input type="password" name="j_password" id="password"
                        style="width: 100%" required></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" style="text-align: right;"><input
                        type="submit" value="Sign in"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" style="color: red; text-align: left;">
                            <c:if test="${param.error != null}">        
                                <c:out value="${param.error}"/>
                            </c:if>

                </tr>

            </table>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you show your login page?

Comment: Yes, sure. (added)

Comment: The log says `AuthenticationServiceException: Authentication method not supported: GET`. Are you sure you're using this form?

Comment: After POST request to j_spring_security_check, i have instantly GET request to j_spring_security_check. I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

You should add csrf key as hidden element in your form:

```
<form action="${loginUrl}" method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="login">Login:</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="j_username" id="login"
                    style="width: 100%" required></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="password">Password:</label></td>
                <td><input type="password" name="j_password" id="password"
                    style="width: 100%" required></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" style="text-align: right;"><input
                    type="submit" value="Sign in"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" style="color: red; text-align: left;">
                        <c:if test="${param.error != null}">        
                            <c:out value="${param.error}"/>
                        </c:if>

            </tr>

        </table>
        <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}" />
    </form>
```